# How to implement owen-it/laravel-auditing in a model

Tags: php, laravel, model, laravel-5.4, audit

I want to create an audit trail in my model. I already installed owen-it/laravel-auditing package via Composer. My question is that how can I implement it in my Model or controller. Please see my code for controller and Model below. Thanks

My Controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Events\Test;
use App\Letter;
use App\Notifications\LetterNotification;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class LetterController extends Controller
{
    public function viewLetter()
    {
        return view('welcome');
    }

    /**
     * Saves email into database
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return Letter
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $letter = Letter::create([
            'email' => $data['email']
        ]);
        $this->letterNotify($letter);

        return $letter;
    }

    /**
     * Validates email
     */
    public function createLetter(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:letters'
        ],[
            'email.required' => 'Email is required.',
            'email.unique' => 'Already registered.',
            'email.email' => 'Please put a valid Email address'
        ]);

        $this->create($request->all());

        return redirect('/')->with('info','You are now registered.');
    }

    protected function letterNotify($letter)
    {`enter code here`
        Notification::send($letter, new LetterNotification($letter));
    }


}
```

For my Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use OwenIt\Auditing\Auditable;
use OwenIt\Auditing\Contracts\Auditable as AuditableContract;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Letter extends Model implements AuditableContract
{
    use Notifiable;

    use Auditable;

    protected $fillable = ['email'];

    protected $table = 'letters';
}
```

Comment: The code you have submitted looks fine. Please explain what's not working, or what you're expecting to see/happen. The [documentation](http://www.laravel-auditing.com/docs/4.0) should have everything you need.

Comment: @QuetzyGarcia Just want to ask if the said laravel-auditing package can be apply in the default package 'Auth'?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Do you want to know if the [user resolver](http://www.laravel-auditing.com/docs/4.0/general-settings) can use a different package rather than `Auth` (`Sentinel`, for example)?

Comment: @QuetzyGarcia I'm referring to a login since I'm using the 'Auth'. My understanding for that laravel-auditing package is that it does not record viewing or logging in. It only records for some data changes or logging out, right?

Comment: The package audits database operations, so if you want to audit a login/logout, you'll have to create a record in the database each time that happens.

Answer (score 2):

Like I stated in my comment, the Laravel Auditing package only triggers an audit on a database operation involving an Eloquent model and event (by default, `created`, `updated`, `deleted`, `restored`).

Having said that, here's a list of steps to create an audit when logging in/out:

- Create a listener for the `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login` event;
- Once fired, update a column in the `users` table that keeps track of the latest login date/time (`latest_login_at`, for example);
- (Optional) update a column with the previous login date/time (`last_login_at`, for example);
- By doing those updates to the `users` table, the `Auditor` kicks in;
- You can also listen for the `OwenIt\Auditing\Events\Auditing` or `OwenIt\Auditing\Events\Audited` events and apply more logic if needed;
- Follow the same steps for the `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout` event;

Comment: Am looking for a way to audit custom events like login and logout can you elaborate more on your answer to clarify on how to achieve this @Quetzy Garcia

Comment: What exactly don't you understand?